# Why do we need to color a node Grey in breadth first search in addition to other colors black and white?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

As given in the book CLRS, while doing a BFS, we color the node grey if it was previously white and would now be inserted into the queue. But we never check whether a node is grey or not. So why do we color a node grey?

Answer (score 2):

The footnote at the bottom of page 594 explains that "We distinguish between gray and black vertices to help us understand how breadth-first search operates. In facts, as Exercise 22.2-3 shows, we would get the same result even if we did not distinguish between gray and black vertices."

So BFS could really be done with just white and black. Gray is used as a tool to  help us visualize how the algorithm operates.

Comment: Please explain precisely, at least use some tags.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your comment, Fatema. Could you clarify? I believe I explained the problem precisely enough. I guess I could have added tags to my answer but not sure what that has to do with the preciseness of my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on quora by Cormen himself: 
https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-need-to-color-a-node-Grey-in-breadth-first-search-in-addition-to-other-colors-black-and-white

Comment: There is an excercise 22.2-3 in the book on page 602 which asks to proof that we can safely remove lines 5 and 14 of the algorithm (only lines where grey is used).

But I still don't get how it will work w/o grey assignment.
There is a comment from Vinh Nguyen on the Quora page you posted:
"Whenever a node is pushed into the queue, it is marked grey so as to prevent the same node being pushed on the queue multiple times by multiple neighbors."

So, why it will work without grey?

Answer (score 0):

First, lets look at how BFS goes through a graph.

Starting with the single given source. we discover all of it's adjacent nodes, then repeat for each node discovered this way.

We are finished once every node is discovered, and there are no more nodes waiting to be processed (in the queue).
So really what we're keeping track of is: "Has this node been reached yet (via a shorter path)?"

With this in mind, we can narrow color down to a boolean value that represents one binary state (discovered / undiscovered), and rely on the queue to hold any nodes that have not yet been fully processed.

In short, if it's black but still in the queue, handle like its gray. (need to peek front before the inner for loop, then dequeue after)